# How to use an action code and then get the current user with firebase?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase

I am designing 2 pages for a user signing up. The first page is where the user enters their email only. I then perform this code.

```
await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email.value, bcrypt.hashSync(email.value, 6))
      .then(async (userCredential) => {
        sendEmailVerification(userCredential.user)
        loading = false
        navigate('/verifyEmail')
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        log.error(`Error registering user: ${error}`)
        errorMessage = error.message
        isEmailInvalid = true
        loading = false
      })
```

This sends the user a verification email, which they then click on to set their password and name:

```
    let oobCode = ''
    oobCode = window.location.href.split('oobCode=')[1].split('&')[0]
    const email = window.location.href.split('email=')[1].split('/')[0]
    let user = auth.currentUser
    await applyActionCode(auth, oobCode)
      .then(async (result) => {
        console.log(auth.currentUser)
        Promise.all([
          updateProfile(auth.currentUser, {displayName: firstName + ' ' + lastName}),
          updatePassword(auth.currentUser, password),
        ])
        console.log('Welcome', firstName, lastName)
        await setUser('local', undefined, auth.currentUser)
      })
```

However at this point, auth.currentUser will be null if the user has clicked on this link on a different browser. A quick workaround would be to create a user with password 'password' and then sign them in after applying the action code. However this has a big security flaw obviously, my current idea just encrypts their email as a temporary password in hopes they cannot guess it and sign in.

I guess my question is, how do I update the user upon applying an action code? If I can't do this what flow of operations should I change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, how do I update the user upon applying an action code?

If the user is using another browser it is not possible since he/she does not know the password.

> If I can't do this what flow of operations should I change?

IMHO you are overcomplexifying the onboarding process. The common approach is to create the account with the password being chosen by the user (which, in your case, should happen in the first screen) and send the email for verification.

**In parallel you deny access to the Firebase back-ends (DBs, Cloud Storage, etc.) to users with non verified email via the Security Rules.**

Upon email verification you sign in the user:

- If it is from the same browser the users is actually already signed in (side effect of the use of `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`
- If it is in a different browser the user just has to enter his email and password (which he/she knows)

Comment: Surely this a complicated approach for any user. Let's say I forgot my password, send a password reset link, open it on my phone (which I usually do), and as updatePassword requires a user, it will not update as getAuth().currentUser will be null. Is firebase just not capable of changing a password from a different device?

Comment: "Is firebase just not capable of changing a password from a different device?" Yes it is possible but if it is done from a front-end the user needs to be logged in and he/she can modify his/her password only. Other solution is to send a [password reset email link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/email-action-links#generate_password_reset_email_link).

Comment: I actually found a function that meets my requirements. It's called confirmPasswordReset. It only requires the auth, oob code and new password. The fact this isn't in the documentation at all is surprising. It doesn't require the user to be signed in and allows them to reset their password on a different device.

Comment: It is actually documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler) and tightly linked to [password reset email link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/email-action-links#generate_password_reset_email_link) I was mentioning in my previous comment.